# How to download current HTML page by button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to download the current HTML page with a button click. When a user would click on the button then an HTML file will be download on the user's local computer. When they will click on the downloaded HTML file then it will open his/her browser and he/she can see exactly the page when he/she downloaded it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb6EA.png)

Comment: just tell them `ctrl`-`s` on your keyboard to save this page

Comment: you mean download this images?

Comment: @Bravo a caveat is that that wouldn't work on MacOS though...

Comment: yeah, ok, on the mac hit whatever key combo is the "save" key combo .... what is it? apple cucumber fidget-spinner or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ya go bit hacky but it works

```
    <button type="submit">
    <a style="text-decoration: none;color: inherit;" onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="page.html">Download</a>
    </button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work without the `href='#'` as well, do you do it to "reset" href? Also, why doesn't it work just with `href` and `download`, as other answers to similar questions suggest?